# vim ~/symlink-to-dir/file resolves symlink to target instead of symlink path

Tags: invocation

`vim ~/symlink-to-dir/file` resolves the symlink and shows me `~/real-dir/file` in the status line and in `echo expand('%')`. After a few hours of experiments I found the problem is reproducible.

The conditions for the bug are (`~/.vim/` and `~/.vimrc` are absent or empty):

- the symlink must be a link to a directory; direct link to a file doesn't trigger the bug; `vim ~/symlink-to-file` shows `~/symlink-to-file`;
- the bug is triggered only in shell command line; `vim` with `:ed ~/symlink-to-dir/file` shows the symlink, not the resolved target;
- the path must be absolute: `vim ~/symlink-to-dir/file` triggers the bug, `vim ../symlink-to-dir/file` doesn't.

I reproduced the bug with different versions of `vim` on different Linux systems. I reproduced the bug with `vim` 7.4 on CentOS with absent `~/.vim/` and `~/.vimrc`. I triggered the bug with `vim` 9.0 at Debian 12.4 with additional condition: `:set laststatus=2` in `~/.vimrc`; absent `laststatus` or other values (0 or 1) don't trigger the bug.

Can anybody reproduce the bug? Could you suggest any workaround to prevent `vim` to resolve the symlink (without changing/removing `statusline=2`)? Should I report this as a bug?

A script to reproduce the bug:

```sh
#! /bin/sh
set -e
cd "$HOME"

trap 'set +e; rm -rf .vim .vimrc test-dir test-syml;
    mv .vim-backup .vim; mv .vimrc-backup .vimrc' EXIT HUP INT QUIT TERM

mv .vim .vim-backup
mv .vimrc .vimrc-backup
rm -rf test-dir test-syml

echo set laststatus=2 > .vimrc

mkdir test-dir
echo Test >test-dir/test-file

ln -s test-dir test-syml
vim -c "echo expand('%')" "$HOME"/test-syml/test-file
```

Expected output (both in the status line and from `expand('%')`) in `vim`: `~/test-syml/test-file`; the actual output is `~/test-dir/test-file`.

Comment: This probably belongs on the Vim bug tracker on GitHub

Comment: I added this to an existing bug report: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/4942#issuecomment-1864917074 . Should I remove the question?

Comment: Your call; assuming this might get fixed, this could help folks find the answer. It’s not off-topic AFAICT, and the up-votes indicate it’s a good question to some degree, so removing isn’t strictly necessary.